# Android Kotlin Gson Slow Json Deserialization

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a large json which i have to deserialize, and i'm only interested of certain parts of if. The Pojos i am using are something like this:

```
data class Response<T>(
        val header: JHeader,
        val result: T
)

data class JHeader(
        val success: Int,
        val error: List<String>
)

class Character{
    @SerializedName("id_") val id: Int
    @SerializedName("levelA") val level: String
    @SerializedName("a3") val unit: String = ""

    constructor(id: Int, level: String) {
        this.id = id
        this.level= level
    }
}
```

Relevant part of the retrofit adapter:

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build()
```

And the Impl:

```
fun getCharacterById(characterID: Int):Observable<Response<List<Character>>> {
        return apiService.getCharacter(characterID)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }
```

I'm getting retrofit debug reports of 300ms for a simple call to this service.

My questions are:

- When should i consider using a TypeAdapter (i opt for performance over boilerplate, i dont mind writing a few extra lines of code with type adapters). But I don't quite understand what type adapters are for, in what scenarios should i use them.
- My Json structure has a lot more attributes than my Character Pojo, i simply realised that using transient / @Expose or keeping it out of the Pojo lead to the same results. Is there any difference between those 3?
- As i'm using Kotlin, is there any library/extension that help me deal with this TypeAdapter deserialization stuff?

Comment: I'm facing similar problems right now. How many bytes is your http response?

Comment: 200 OK (303ms), END HTTP (49063-byte body)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me implementing a custom `TypeAdapter` was a huge performance boost. I use type adapters for every class which needs to be deserialized in huge amounts. In your example that would be (in Java):

```
public class CharacterTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Character> {
    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Character character) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();
        out.name("id").value(character.getId());
        out.name("level").value(character.getLevel());
        out.name("unit").value(character.getUnit());
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Character read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        Character character = new Character();
        in.beginObject();
        while(in.hasNext()){
            switch(in.nextName()){
                case "id":
                   character.setId(in.nextInt());
                   break; 
                case "level":
                   character.setId(in.nextString());
                   break;
                case "unit":
                   character.setId(in.nextString());
                   break;
            }
        }
        in.endObject();

        return character;
    }
}
```

The `TypeAdapter` must be registered in your Gson configuration as follows:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Character.class, new CharacterTypeAdapter());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

The gson instance must be registered with Retrofit:

```
 new Retrofit
     .Builder()
     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
     .build()
     .createApi(Api.class);
```

You get blazing fast deserialization.

Comment: ya i have realised it might be something like that, but i think im getting the same results and i don't know if it is the server that is slow, has i have no way of benchmarking the default json deserialisation. Any idea how to measure it?

Comment: for some reason, son isn't using my type adapter. weird.

Comment: It seems that Generic Lists with a custom TypeAdapter for its objects won't get recognised and so the default deserialiser is used. any workaround?

Comment: I cant't confirm this. I'm using it for generic lists too. The only difference i see is that my retrofit api methods don't wrap the result in a `Response` object, i.e. `Observable<List<Character>>` instead of `Observable<Response<List<Character>>>`. I don't know if this makes a difference for deserialization though.

Comment: im almost sure it does :p but could find a solution yet